# Esp32 Bluetooth Low Energy get RSSI strength from iOS & Android

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, rssi

**I need to setup my Esp32-D1-Mini to read RSSI from both my iPhone and Nexus 5x** (not at the same time of course, in other words I'd like it to work with both operating systems and read RSSI from them continously).

**I've managed to make it work with Bluetooth Classic but that only works with Android OS smartphones** and I need to have it work with iOS devices as well, so **I had to switch to using BLE** and this looks much more complicated.

**The Esp32 is setup to work as a Server** which anyone can connect to.

It is supposed to wait for a device to connect to it and as soon as that device is connected the Esp32 should start reading RSSI strength continously (with a 1 second delay) until the other device disconnects then enter back in "sleep mode" and wait for another device to connect to it.

The code I have right now has a few problems which I struggle to solve:

1. **It won't read any RSSI whatsoever from my iPhone**, after it connects to the Esp32 using the LightBlue App
2. After my Android phone connects to the Esp32, using the nRF Connect app, it will read the RSSI values just once, instead of continuing to read them until the phone disconnects or it loses signal to the Esp32.
3. **The iPhone will not reveal its Mac adress after connecting** (no mac adress appears at all) **which in response won't let my Esp32 read any RSSI values from the iPhone** and from what I've understood I need to request pairing from my Esp32 when the iPhone wants to connect to it in order for the iPhone to reveal its MAC Address and get RSSI from it (but I didn't find any example of how to achieve that, at least not by using Arduino), that is because the Esp32 first needs a MAC Adress of the device I want to read RSSI from, being it already connected to the Esp32 or not; the iphone does not reveal its Mac Adress after connecting so I guess I have to force it to pair when any iOS device tries to connect to the Esp32 in order to fetch their Mac Address and read their rssi.
4. The RSSI values start from 0 when they are read from my Android phone and they go up; I've managed to write the code first time using Bluetooth Classic and I really liked the way the RSSI would show, which would be 0 when standing close to the Esp32 (after connecting to it) and when getting away decreasing to -5, -10, etc. I'd like to read the rssi in the same way if possible, not from 0 up.
   See my BT Classic Code at the bottom.

**This is my current code** (I've used the Esp32 Ble Client example as a starting point):

```
    #include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEScan.h>

// See the following for generating UUIDs:
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

const int PIN = 2;
bool deviceConnected = false;

  static void my_gap_event_handler(esp_gap_ble_cb_event_t event, esp_ble_gap_cb_param_t* param) {

  Serial.print("RSSI status");Serial.println(param->read_rssi_cmpl.status);
  Serial.print("RSSI ");Serial.println(param->read_rssi_cmpl.rssi);
  Serial.print("Address ");Serial.println(BLEAddress(param->read_rssi_cmpl.remote_addr).toString().c_str());
  
}

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600);

  BLEDevice::init("Long name works now");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ|BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE);
  BLEDevice::setCustomGapHandler(my_gap_event_handler);
  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World says Neil");
  pService->start();
//BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();  // this still is working for backward compatibility
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();

  pinMode (PIN, OUTPUT);//Specify that Vibration Motor pin is output
  
}

void loop() {  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 
  delay(1000);
  
}
```

I bassically want to have the BLE code doing what my BT Classic code does (I don't need help with setting up the distance meassuring and the kalman filter, I think I know how to configure them myself);

**I only need help with getting the Esp32 to read the RSSI continously from any iOS & Android** devices trying to connect to the Esp32.

**Here is my Bluetooth Classic Code** (working well but with Android OS devices only):

```
    #include "esp_bt_main.h"
#include "esp_gap_bt_api.h"
#include "esp_bt_device.h"
#include "BluetoothSerial.h" //Header File for Serial Bluetooth, will be added by default into Arduino
#include "esp_gap_bt_api.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "Kalman.h"
 
// My function prototypes
void gap_callback (esp_bt_gap_cb_event_t event, esp_bt_gap_cb_param_t *param);
void spp_callback (esp_spp_cb_event_t event, esp_spp_cb_param_t *param);
 
 
//Creates the variables:
double measurement, filteredMeasurement;
Kalman myFilter(0.125,32,1023,0); //suggested initial values for high noise filtering
 
       // this->q = process_noise;
       // this->r = sensor_noise;
       // this->p = estimated_error;
       // this->x = intial_value; //x will hold the iterated filtered value
 
uint8_t link_master;
 
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
 
int rssi = 0; //RSSI
 
/* Kalman filter variables */
 
    double q; //process noise covariance
    double r; //measurement noise covariance
    double x; //value
    double p; //estimation error covariance
    double k; //kalman gain
 
        
//distance = pow(10, ((refOneMeter - recvRSSI) / (10 * estPathLossExp))) //formula for distance meassurement
// we need variables to hold refOneMeter, recvRSSI, and estPathLossExp
 
byte addr[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //to keep MAC address of the remote device , 8 bit value
 
static int PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN; //The user will be prompted to enter a pin or an app will enter a pin for user
 
struct read_rssi_delta_param;
struct esp_bt_gap_cb_param_t::read_rssi_delta_param read_rssi_delta; //read rssi parameter struct
 
esp_bd_addr_t bda; //remote bluetooth device address
 
int8_t rssi_delta; //rssi delta value range -128 ~127, The value zero indicates that the RSSI is inside the Golden Receive Power Range, the Golden Receive Power Range is from ESP_BT_GAP_RSSI_LOW_THRLD to ESP_BT_GAP_RSSI_HIGH_THRLD
 
esp_err_t esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta(esp_bd_addr_t remote_addr); //This function is called to read RSSI delta by address after connected. The RSSI value returned by ESP_BT_GAP_READ_RSSI_DELTA_EVT.
 
BluetoothSerial ESP32Mini_Bluetooth; //Object for Bluetooth
 
 
//ESP32Mini_Bluetooth_GAP_READ_RSSI_DELTA_EVT; //read RSSI event
//ESP_BT_GAP_DEV_PROP_RSSI; // Received Signal strength Indication, value type is int8_t, ranging from -128 to 127
//ESP_BT_GAP_RSSI_LOW_THRLD; // Low RSSI threshold
//ESP_BT_GAP_RSSI_HIGH_THRLD; //     RSSI threshold. High RSSI threshold
 
//esp_bd_addr_t bda; //remote bluetooth device address
//esp_bt_status_t stat; //read rssi status
 
 
const int PIN = 32;
const int CUTOFF = -60;
int incoming;
int best;
 
float distance = 0.0;
 
void setup() {
 
  ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.setPin("4321"); //This should solve the Secured Pin Connection
 
  SerialBT.begin();
 
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start Serial monitor in 9600 ; this is the line where it initialize serial to 9600 baud speed
 
  // this->q = process_noise;
  // this->r = sensor_noise;
  // this->p = estimated_error;
  // this->x = intial_value; //x will hold the iterated filtered value
 
 // float temp1  = ((-6) - (rssi));
 // float temp2 = (temp1 / 100);
 //  distance= pow(10,temp2);
 // distance = pow(10, (-6 - rssi) / (100));  
  
  ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.begin("Esp32-Mini"); //Name of your Bluetooth Signal
  Serial.println("Bluetooth Device is Ready to Pair");
 
  pinMode (PIN, OUTPUT);//Specify that Vibration Motor pin is output
 
  esp_bt_gap_register_callback (gap_callback); //register the RSSI callback function by calling this line
 
  //register SPP service callback to get remote address:
  SerialBT.register_callback(spp_callback);
 
  // //This is Legacy Pairing Code
  //ESP_BT_GAP_PIN_REQ_EVT //Legacy Pairing Pin code request
  //ESP_BT_GAP_CFM_REQ_EVT //Simple Pairing User Confirmation request.
  //ESP_BT_GAP_KEY_NOTIF_EVT //Simple Pairing Passkey Notification
  //ESP_BT_GAP_KEY_REQ_EVT //Simple Pairing Passkey request
 
}
 
void loop() {
 
  delay(100);
  if (SerialBT.hasClient()) { //this is where we get and handle RSSI value
 
    //when we need RSSI call this:
    esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta (addr); //now variable rssi contains RSSI level
    byte b = rssi; //etc....
 
    //reads measurement and filter it
  measurement = (double) rssi; //read new value from rssi
  filteredMeasurement = myFilter.getFilteredValue(measurement);
 
       float temp1 = (3) - (rssi);
       float temp2 = (temp1 / 100);
       distance = pow(10,temp2);
        
    if (rssi < -10)
    {
      digitalWrite(PIN, HIGH);
      //ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.println("Vibration Motor ON");
      //Serial.print ("PIN turned ON");
    }
 
    if (rssi > -10)
    {
      digitalWrite(PIN, LOW);
      //ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.println("Vibration Motor OFF");
      //Serial.print ("PIN turned OFF");
 
    }
 
    
 
    //ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.print("RSSI: "); //println add linefeed for end of printed string
    //ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.println(rssi); //println add linefeed for end of printed string
    
     
      //ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.print(", ");
       //ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.println(filteredMeasurement);     
      
      ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.print(rssi);      
      ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.print(", ");
      ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.println(distance);
 
//So building up the serial, we have  filtered: <value>  TAB
//we are adding   filtered: <value>  TAB distance: <value> TAB  rssi: <value>
      
      Serial.print ("filtered:");
      Serial.print (filteredMeasurement);
      Serial.print ("\t distance:");
      Serial.print (distance);
      Serial.print ("\t rssi:");
      Serial.print (rssi);
    
    delay (1000);    //DELAY OF 1 SECONDS
  }
  else
  {
    // Disconnected state
      digitalWrite(PIN, LOW);
     // Serial.println ("Disconnected. PIN turned OFF");
      Serial.println (rssi);
      delay(1000); // wait 1s
  }
 
  if (ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.available()) //Check if we receive anything from Bluetooth // is telling that BT has received some data and it need to be processed
  {
    incoming = ESP32Mini_Bluetooth.read(); //Read what we recevive
    Serial.print("Received:"); Serial.println(incoming);
    digitalWrite(PIN, best > CUTOFF ? HIGH : LOW);
    
  }
}
 
 
//RSSI callback function
void gap_callback (esp_bt_gap_cb_event_t event, esp_bt_gap_cb_param_t *param)
{
  if (event == ESP_BT_GAP_READ_RSSI_DELTA_EVT)
  {
    rssi = param->read_rssi_delta.rssi_delta; // it checks it has connection
    Serial.print("\t RSSI Delta: ");
    Serial.println (param->read_rssi_delta.rssi_delta);
  }
}
 
//SPP service callback function (to get remote MAC address)
void spp_callback (esp_spp_cb_event_t event, esp_spp_cb_param_t *param)
{
  if (event == ESP_SPP_SRV_OPEN_EVT)
    memcpy(addr, param->srv_open.rem_bda, 6);
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this, i have a similar problem.